# Sparkle Framework and the Mac App Store: Best practices?

Tags: macos, cocoa, mac-app-store, sparkle

What is your approach when it comes to distributing via the Mac App Store and having been using the Sparkle framework.

I found these two sites that mention the problems and how to resolve these but I'd like to know how you handle this.

http://furbo.org/2011/03/09/mac-app-store-guide/

http://danielkennett.org/blog/2010/12/techniques-for-managing-optional-code/

Thanks everyone.

**[Update]**

Here's another approach:

http://bruji.com/articles/2011/02/09/conditionally-building-a-mac-app-store-applications-to-exclude-sparkle/

Comment: Are you looking to maintain both versions?

Comment: Yes, both versions is what I'd like to have.

Comment: The Craig Hockenberry article is pretty much dead-on in terms of what you need to look for.  Is there something in particular you don't like about that approach?  We use a slight variation, but the philosophy is the same.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'm just curious which way devs go nowadays since that Hockenberry-post is 2 years old.

Comment: For this, not much has changed.   There's really not any better technology than conditional compilation.   I will say that if you have the framework in your app at all, you will be rejected by the AppStore (been there, done that), so make sure that's neither linked nor copied in.